# Best ML technique to suggest predictor variables

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, pca, scikit-learn

Imagine the following dataset:

First 4 columns are predictor variables and the *engine running index* is the response variable.

```
   O2 level | Cylinder pressure | Fuel Flow | Engine temp | Engine running index
       5              15               3           31                7
       2              31              18            1               88
       1              22              66            4               31
      ...            ...              ...          ...             ...
```

Situation: An engineer comes with a similar data set and asks a question: "*What should be the setting of my O2 level, cylinder pressure etc to get the best running index?*"

Now one could take a statistical approach and try figure out the answer but I was looking to employ some machine learning technique. The ones Ive tried, i.e. Regression, but its used more to **predict** what the *Engine running index* will be rather than suggest what the settings should be to get the best *running index*.
The other one I was looking at was PCA, but not sure that it will give me an answer as well.

Note: the possible max value for *Engine running index* is not known.

So my question is simple: are there ML techniques to help me answer engineer's question?

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Regression is quite well suited for learning what settings generate the best running index (or at least a good running index). All you need is in the regression coefficients. If the regression coefficient is positive, a greater value of the corresponding regressor will tend to yield a greater value of the response*. You want to maximize the response; hence, the recipe is to increase (maximize) the regressor value. Conversely, if the regression coefficient is negative, minimize the corresponding regressor's value. That is the answer the engineer needs.

Consider a concrete example. Suppose the fitted regression equation is
$$
y=0.5+2x_1-0.5x_2+\varepsilon.
$$
Since $2>0$, an increase in $x_1$ should hopefully yield an increase in $y$. Thus the engineer should seek to increase $x_1$ as much as possible. On the other hand, since $-0.5<0$, an increase in $x_2$ would yield a decrease in $y$. Therefore the engineer should minimize $x_2$ to maximize $y$.

**Edit:** as Matthew Drury points out, a simple regression like this need not be a good model for your particular application. (Perhaps some feature engineering would make it better.) The important thing is that *if* the model has decent fit, *then* it can be used conveniently for finding settings in which the response is maximized.

---

*<sub>This requires some assumptions such as exogeneity of the regressor.</sub>

Comment: You're also assuming that it is possible to fit the data well with a linear function of the predictors.  There's no ap-priori reason to believe this is true.  So while I agree that regression is a good approach, I think in practice it's more complicated than just throwing all the raw predictors in a linear regression.  The OP will have to do some exploratory data analysis to determine what fits for the predictors are appropriate.  If they are non-linear, the model will have to be used in an optimization scheme to determine the best parameters.  I do agree with this approach.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, I agree. What I wanted to point out is that regression is a tool that can be used directly for the task (contrary to the OP's assertion). Now it requires some skill, for sure, but so do the alternative tools.

Comment: Agree completely.

Comment: Although the suggestion is contrary to my initial assertation, I overlooked these properties provided by using regression technique. I shall start my investigation and come back to you, thank you (both @MatthewDrury && Richard Hardy)